# How to change playback speed of live audio from microphone (using a buffer)?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have heard that by changing playback speed we can modify the frequency of the audio. I have tested it here : 
https://teropa.info/blog/2016/08/10/frequency-and-pitch.html

But the problem is that I need a recorded audio file to do that. From what I have found web audio can't change playback speed of live audio. I have been thinking that if we save the audio in buffer we can change its playback speed thus changing the frequency.

I am new to web-audio API. I have found an article that records live audio by saving it to the buffer. https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/articles/webaudio-1/

What I want is :-

1. Get audio from mic.
2. Save it into buffer.
3. Change Playback speed.
4. Play on the speakers.

Demo explaining how to change playback speed of a buffernode https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/decode-audio-data/

But I want live mic audio to be used in place of recorded sound.

Here is my try on fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5dza62b8/13/

```
var audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var streamSource, scriptNode, bufferSource, audioBuffer;
var playbackControl = document.querySelector('#playback-rate-control');
var playbackValue = document.querySelector('#playback-rate-value');

// define variables

window.start_audio = function() {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }).then((stream) => {

    alert("Got audio stream from microphone!");
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    streamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
    bufferSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();


    // Whenever onaudioprocess event is dispatched it creates a buffer array with the length bufferLength
    scriptNode.onaudioprocess = (audioProcessingEvent) => {
      realtimeBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      // Create an array of buffer array
      audioBuffer.push(realtimeBuffer);
    }

    bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
    bufferSource.playbackRate.value = 0.8;

    streamSource.connect(scriptNode);
    bufferSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
    bufferSource.start();

  }).catch((e) => {

    alert(e.name + ". " + e.message);

  });
}


// wire up buttons to stop and play audio, and range slider control
playbackControl.addEventListener('input', function() {
  bufferSource.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
  playbackValue.innerHTML = playbackControl.value;
});
```

Comment: Héhé, you may not notice, but you are asking for a time machine ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido, If live audio is t sec lag, think of t + 2 seconds with different pitch by adjusting the playback speed assuming we save 1 sec of audio into the buffer and it takes about 1 sec lag more for the complete process. 

If this is possible, I would like to do then I will try to reduce lag from 2 sec to about 30 ms.

Comment: If you only want to lower the pitch, then yes it's very feasible: https://jsfiddle.net/08ctfzp1/ But if you want to increase it, then it's not possible: If you do buffer 2s of live audio, then play it a speed x2, it will take only 1s to read what was buffered when the playback started, so during this playback, you'd have buffered only one second of live audio, that you'll read in 50ms, where you'll be able to buffer only 25ms that you'll read in 12.5ms etc. after roughly 1.99999 seconds you'll reach the present.

Comment: Good effort, but like you said it starts buffering after few secs. Are there any other methods to change pitch without making the sound robotic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476612/webaudio-api-change-pitch-of-samples-for-example-mp3

Comment: @Kaiido, Already tried the jungle.js for changing pitch. It works but the effect is robotic and sounds distorted.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a harder problem than you think – if the playback speed is greater than 1, you'll be trying to play sounds that haven't happened yet!

In general though, you *can* use the web audio API to add effects to live microphone input – here's an example from the MDN documentation which adds a filter to the input: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource

If you want to slow the live audio down, it *is* possible – with some caveats. The Web Audio node which allows you to change the playback rate is a BufferSourceNode, which relies on you having loaded the buffer previously. However, you could probably work around this by using a custom AudioWorklet to incrementally put the data into a buffer and play it back using a BufferSourceNode. One thing to consider is how long you'd let this go on for – the buffer would just keep getting bigger and bigger as time went on, and sooner or later your computer would run out of memory!

This is quite involved, and might not be ideal for a first foray into Web Audio, but the best jumping-off point to learn about audio worklets is here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet

Using an audio worklet, you could also investigate some more sophisticated algorithms which would allow you to change the pitch of a sound without changing its length. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time_stretching_and_pitch_scaling

If you're just getting started with web audio, my recommendation would be that you write something that lets you record a sound, *then* change its playback rate.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/08ctfzp1/) is an example of Buffering a stream using MediaSource and MediaRecorder (originally for [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934811/pause-the-stream-returned-by-getusermedia/49936122#49936122)) note that FF has problems with the fiddle...

Comment: @Anonymous, If you can see in my code, I am trying to reduce the playback speed from 1 to 0.8. I think this seems poosible, don't you feel the same?

Comment: I want the output which is very close to humans real voice, other methods won't work for me because they make the sound robotic and modified instead of just altering the pitch.